# SecretsManager rule not triggering even though event exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I can see that an event is being fired by the doppler user, but the rule is not getting triggered for some reason I don't know how to debug.

Event fired:

[image: event fired by aws]

Rule pattern:

[image: rule pattern]

I have this simple rule to catch updates to the secrets manager, I can see secrets are being updated and the event being fired, why would my rule not be fired? How could I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a rule with `detail-type` of `AWS API Call via CloudTrail`. In order for these events to be picked up, you must create a [CloudTrail Trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-and-update-a-trail.html):

[image]

Form the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-ct-api-tutorial.html):

> To record events with a detail-type value of AWS API Call via CloudTrail, a CloudTrail trail with logging enabled is required.